# Check OpenID Connect user against local web application users with OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, openid-connect

I need to add OpenID Connect authentication to an existing ASP.NET MVC web application. For that, I am using OWIN.

Once the user has been successfully authenticated by the authentication server (Azure Active Directory in my case), I need to check that the user can be mapped to a local account in my web application. If the user has no valid local account, the actual login process should fail. Is there a standard way to do that?

In the sample I have found (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp), it seems that as soon as the user is successfully authenticated by Azure, then it is logged in the application. Can we add custom code to the OWIN-OIDC sign-in process to perform additional checks?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Good question and there are 2 levels here, as you are finding:

- Authenticating with the Authorization Server / Identity Provider
- Access to the application being allowed

If the first is successful but the second is not, then the standard behaviour is to redirect the user to an 'Access Denied' page (this page must allow anonymous access, to avoid a redirect loop). The login has not failed, but the user is not authorized to access the app.

OWIN uses response_type='code id_token' meaning that you will have an Open Id Connect User Identity to work with. If you can't find the user in your own data you can perform a redirect in the below callback:

```
var openidOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        // Point to a callback to check the identity against my own system
        // This callback can perform a redirect if the app does not recognise the user
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = HandleAuthorizationCodeReceived
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Is there a good reason to use openidOptions.Notifications.AuthorizationCodeReceived and not openidOptions.CallbackPath?

Comment: You need to code some logic to see if the user exists in your system once the login redirect has returned to your app. AuthorizationCodeReceived is a function and you can insert the logic there, once you have the user identity (based on the id token). CallbackPath is just a value so you cannot code logic there.